# PHP echo field, field appears before div

Tags: php, wordpress, echo, advanced-custom-fields

I have the following code:

> `if( get_field('event_timedate') ):  echo "<div class='bm-event_timedate'><p>".the_field('event_timedate')."</p></div>"; endif;`

But for some reason the output is (the date appears before the div and p tags)

> `27/08/2022 8:00pm <div class='bm-event_timedate'><p>".the_field('event_timedate')."</p></div>`

Id really appreciate any help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

use `get_field()` function for echo as well

```
if( get_field('event_timedate') ):
    echo "<div class='bm-event_timedate'><p>".get_field('event_timedate')."</p></div>"; 
endif;
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to the_field()
this function itself displays data but you insert the display data function inside echo.

either you can do like

```
if( get_field('event_timedate') ):
  echo "<div class='bm-event_timedate'><p>";
  the_field('event_timedate');
  echo "</p></div>";
endif;
```

OR

you can use get_field() function instead of the_field() function;

```
if( get_field('event_timedate') ):
   echo "<div class='bm-event_timedate'><p>". get_field ('event_timedate')."</p></div>";
endif;
```